# Why jersey-server.jar is a broken archive?

Tags: java, maven, jersey

This is what I'm doing:

```
$ wget wget --no-check-certificate --quiet \
https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.4/jersey-server-1.4.jar
$ tar tf jersey-server-1.4.jar
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/
tar: Bad ZIP file: Unexpected end-of-entry record
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

Is it my mistake or a problem with the file in JBoss repository?

ps. The same story at this URL: `http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.4/jersey-server-1.4.jar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JAR file is a form of ZIP file, not a TAR file.  Use the `unzip` command to unpack it.  Or better still, use the `jar` utility from your Java installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try another location, actually I'm using :

```
wget http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.4/jersey-server-1.4.jar
```

I've just tried it is correct